# How to know if vpn is on while app is running?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

Since of all the new vpns that have adblock inside of them,based on my anylatics (comparing to active dailt users and time spent, and ads imprissons the numbers are quit different ),which means alot of my users are enabling adblock in there phone,which is really bad to us developers who depends on ads for revenue).
My question Is it possible to know when applaunchs if the users has vpn enabled?
Because i want to disable them for entering until the vpn is removed (turned off)

Answer (score 0):

Check `NEVPNManager.sharedManager.connection.status`